# Node Schedule, delete function deleting users instead of targeted data

Tags: express, node-schedule

```
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 4 * * *',
  function (fireDate) {
    console.log(`fireDate: ${fireDate}`);
    console.log(`now: ${new Date()}`);
    resetUserData()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(`data removed at ${new Date()}`);
        console.log('result:\n', result);
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.error(`removing data failed at ${new Date()}`);
        console.error(`reason: ${reason}`);
      });
  });




function resetUserData(){
  return db('users')
  .select('water', 'exercise', 'sleep', 'breaks', 'daily_points')
  .del()

}
```

The reset function data should delete data based on the .select? It's instead deleting the entire user.

Comment: Do you want to reset/delete the fields in the `select` option of your query? or you want to delete a user based on those criteria?

Comment: I would like to reset the data in the select. back to 0 every day

Comment: Then this won't work. As far as this is concerned you are telling it to delete the USER in particular. To achieve what you want, you'd need to write an update script that would run against each user and reset each of the fields you specify.

Comment: do you know how I could go about doing this? I do have a update function, but it requires an endpoint to be hit.